# Access to collection from client folder

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

Hi im getting started with meteor, so i have a problem: I can't access to collection from client folder
my project struct is default: `meteor create testApp`

```
/testApp
--.Meteor/
--testApp.html
--testApp.css
--testApp.js
```

then i create a mongo collection i add it to `testApp.js`

```
city = new Mongo.Collection('data');
```

running the app with `meteor` command, then i access to chrome console
`city.find().fetch()`; it work perfect and it return the cities

but when i move testApp.js , testApp.css , testApp.html to new folder named `/client`

```
/testApp
--.Meteor/
--client/
----testApp.html
----testApp.css
----testApp.js
```

i cant get the collection from chrome console it mean `city.find().fetch();` return `[]`

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior. `client` and `server` are considered special folders by meteor, where respectively only the client or the server will execute the code that they contain. It is the equivalent of an implicit `if (Meteor.isServer)`

When you declare a collection in the `client` folder *only*, it will only create an empty collection in your client-side database, MiniMongo. Therefore, your MiniMongo collection has no link to any server-side, "real" mongodb collection. That is why you cannot access the data saved into your actual mongodb database.

So in order to fix this, what you can do is either:

- declare your collection once in a separate js file, outside of your `client` and `server` folders so that both sides are aware of that collection (**recommended in most cases**). I use a `collections` folder at the root of my app for that
- declare your collection twice : once in your `client` folder like you did, and another time in the `server` folder at the root of your app (**useful in specific cases such as capped collections, etc**)

Comment: Hi @BraveKenny, how i cant fix that ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to give a solution... updating my answer.

Comment: yeah i create a folder `collections` i create a file and i set `city = new Mongo.Collection('data');` but it still not work ??

Comment: This is strange then. If you go to your app's folder in another terminal while meteor is running, run `meteor mongo` and `db.data.find();` do you get your cities?

Comment: And the `collections` folder is at the root of your app, right? Outside of `client`?

Comment: Yeah! this is working you just have to make a folder outside the clients directory. Also directory and file name can be anything.